# NUKE getting slower with every rendered Frame

Tags: rendering, nuke

I am currently trying to render out an .exr sequence out of a simple nuke script that uses rotopaint and smart-vectors. However, upon rendering out the .exr files, the render-speed gets slower and slower with every frame rendered. When I cancel the rendering and resume from the frame it left off, the rendering is fast again, yet getting slower and slower until coming to a halt around 20 frames in.

Why is that? I checked the cache-path, made sure enough space was free and am sure to be rendering with the GPU. This is a very strange problem that I have never encountered before.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without actually seeing the script, but one possibility has to do with the rotopaint node and the clone brush (if any are used). Sourcing from other frames in nuke often causes recomputation. the smart vector node also sources information from other frames. You might have more luck if you pre-render the smartvectors or the output of the paint (whichever comes first)